# How to style the elements of select field of ACF seperately

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a select field with options of sub and raw it means if I checked raw in my post then raw will appear on front page and if I check sub then sub will show on page. Problem is that when raw displays on page its background color should be yellow and when sub displays its background color should be blue but I cannot assign two colors separately to both fields.

Here is the function to get the field:

```
<span class="rawsubtype3"><?php the_field('type3'); ?></span>
```